# Remove MultiOption from select with optgroup in Zend Forms

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

How can I remove a option from a optgroup in Zend Forms? 
RemoveMultiOption works only if the select does not have a optgroup (it does not work for options inside a opt group).

Any idea perhaps? Thanks!